# java: Building a Tri-nary tree and my nodes won't be deleted

Tags: java, memory, allocation

Building a tribunary tree in Java and my delete functionality doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help me understand why won't delete variable node?

```
node = null;
```

My Code, just compile and run:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class tritree {

public static void main(String[] args) {
new tritree().run();
}

static class TriNode {
TriNode left;
TriNode middle;
TriNode right;

int value;

public TriNode(int value) {
this.value = value;
}
}

private Map<Integer,String> triTreeLevels=new HashMap<Integer, String>();

public void run() {
// build the simple tree from chapter 11.
TriNode root = new TriNode(50);
System.out.println("Binary Tree Example");
System.out.println("Building tree with root value " + root.value);
insert(root, 25);
insert(root, 30);
insert(root, 10);
insert(root, 100);
insert(root, 190);
insert(root, 80);
insert(root, 89);
insert(root, 75);
insert(root, 150);
insert(root, 200);
insert(root, 125);
insert(root, 175);
insert(root, 999);
deleteNode(root, 999);

System.out.println("Traversing tree in order");
printByOrder(root);
j
System.out.println("Tree by levels");
printByOrder(root);
printByTreeLevels(root);

deleteNode(root, 100);
System.out.println("Deleting 100");
System.out.println("Tree by levels");
printByTreeLevels(root);

deleteNode(root, 10);
System.out.println("Deleting 10");
System.out.println("Tree by levels");
printByTreeLevels(root);

deleteNode(root, 200);
System.out.println("Deleting 200");
System.out.println("Tree by levels");
printByTreeLevels(root);

}

public void insert(TriNode node, int value) {
if (value < node.value) {
if (node.left != null) {
insert(node.left, value);
} else {
System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to left of " + node.value);
node.left = new TriNode(value);
}
} else if (value == node.value) {
if(node.middle != null){
insert(node.middle, value);
}else{
System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to middle of " + node.value);
node.middle = new TriNode(value);
}
} else if (value > node.value) {
if (node.right != null) {
insert(node.right, value);
} else {
System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to right of " + node.value);
node.right = new TriNode(value);
}
}
}

public void printByOrder(TriNode node) {
//Prints the existing node and calls print on children
if (node != null) {
printByOrder(node.left);

if(node.middle != null){
printByOrder(node.middle);
}

System.out.println("  Traversed " + node.value);
printByOrder(node.right);
}
}

public void printByTreeLevels(TriNode node){
//clear triTreeLevels from previous fills
triTreeLevels.clear();
loadTreeLevels(node, 0);
displayTreeLevels();
}

public void loadTreeLevels(TriNode node, int level) {
//Add current node to the specified level.
if(triTreeLevels.get(level) != null)
triTreeLevels.put(level, triTreeLevels.get(level) + node.value + " ");
else
triTreeLevels.put(level, node.value + " ");

//This next section loads any existing children nodes in the next level
if(node.left != null)
loadTreeLevels(node.left, level+1);

if(node.middle != null)
loadTreeLevels(node.middle, level+1);

if(node.right != null)
loadTreeLevels(node.right, level+1);
}

public void displayTreeLevels() {
//incremently print the levels of the tree
for(int i = 0; i <  triTreeLevels.size(); i++){
System.out.println(i+": "+triTreeLevels.get(i));
}
}

public void deleteNode(TriNode node, int value) {
if(node.value < value){
deleteNode(node.right, value);
}else if(node.value > value){
deleteNode(node.left, value);
}else{
if(node.left == null && node.middle == null && node.right == null){
//Node is a leaf, safe to remove
node = null;
}else if(node.middle != null){
//Node contains a duplicate which will be used as it's spare
node = node.middle;
}else if(node.left != null && node.right == null){
//Node only contains a left, so it's removed by being replaced with the left node
node = node.left;
}else if(node.left == null &&  node.middle == null && node.right != null){
//Node only contains a right, so it's removed by being replaced with the right node
node = node.right;
}else{
//At this point we lose the complexity of 3 children. If the deleted node had a duplicate it would have been replaced.
if(node.right.left == null){
//Right node doesn't have a left child

//Right node inherits the left node as a left child
node.right.left = node.left;
//and replaces the current one
node = node.right;
}else{
TriNode replacementNode;
TriNode parentOfLowestNode = node.right;

//Keep traversing until we find the lowest value on the left side
while(parentOfLowestNode.left.left != null)
parentOfLowestNode = parentOfLowestNode.left;

//Replacement node will be the lowest value
replacementNode = parentOfLowestNode.left;

//lowest value is the node all the way to the left
//it will be replaced with it's right child if it has one
parentOfLowestNode.left = replacementNode.right;

//Finish building the replacement node by supplying it's left and right children with those of the node to be deleted
replacementNode.left = node.left;
replacementNode.right = node.right;

//replace the node to be deleted
node = replacementNode;
}
}
}
}

}
```

Comment: The proper term is not trinary or tribunary, it's ternary. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node = null` simply sets the reference `node` to null. It's not actually deleting the node in the tree. To delete the node in the tree, you must set the `left`, `middle`, or `right` variable of the parent node to null.

`node` is simply a local, temporary variable used by the method `deleteNode()` to reference the node you want to be deleted.

Comment: So I'm new to java - but couldn't I make the parameter in deleteNode() a pointer or reference to the actual memory to delete it?

Comment: @Travis: No. Java is a *safe* language, in that there is no (supported) way to manipulate memory directly. And even Java allowed unsafe code, and you could delete the memory containing the node object, you would still have what's called a *dangling pointer* bug, because other objects would be referencing a now-deleted object.